# Javascript: nice human readable join of list

Tags: javascript

Having a list (array) of tags `['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']` I want to generate a nice title like: `Content tagged tag1, tag2 and tag3`.

For the moment I have:

```
"Content tagged " + tags_titles.join(" and ");
```

with the result:
`Content tagged tag1 and tag2 and tag3`

I know it's a simple question, but I am curious if there is a nice solution for this case.

Comment: is the order of the tags relevant?

Comment: No. It is not...

Comment: If needed check if the answers also work with arrays of length 0 and 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could get the two last elements and join them with `' and '` and put it as last element back into the array and later join all elements with `', '` for getting a nice string.

Methods

- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), joins two arrays and returns a new array
- [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), for getting the last two elemensts of the array
- [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), joins an array with the given spacer.

This proposal works for any length of an array, even with one or two elements.

```js
function nice([...array]) {
    return array.concat(array.splice(-2, 2).join(' and ')).join(', ');
}

console.log("Content tagged " + nice(['tag1']));
console.log("Content tagged " + nice(['tag1', 'tag2']));
console.log("Content tagged " + nice(['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']));
```

Comment: Should probably handle null/undefined `array` a bit better. Also, stop writing better javascript than me! ;)

Comment: @Jamiec, feel free to add some sanity checks.

Comment: Just to note: this function is **not pure** and will modify the input array, which will lead to inevitable bugs. It would be better to copy the array before joining it. `array = array.slice()`

Comment: @RickLancee, right, just work with a copy, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of slicing and dicing using `Array.prototype.slice`:

```js
function naturalLanguageJoin(arr){
    if(!arr)
       return '';
    if(arr.length<2)
       return (arr.length>0) ? arr[0] : '';
    return arr.slice(0,arr.length-1).join(", ") + " and " + arr[arr.length-1];
}

console.log(naturalLanguageJoin(['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']));
console.log(naturalLanguageJoin(['tag1', 'tag2']));
console.log(naturalLanguageJoin(['tag1']));
console.log(naturalLanguageJoin([]));
console.log(naturalLanguageJoin(null));
```

Answer (score 2):

An array can be treated as a stack so you can pop the last element and in turn write this

```
var last = tags_titles.pop();
last = tags_titles.length ? ` and ${last}` : last;
`Content tagged ${tags_titles.join(", ")} ${last}`
```

The code uses ES6 string templates, which I generally find to be more readable than doing string concatenation in the code. It also utilizes the fact that the pop method essentially performs to operations. Gets the lasst element of the array and mutate the array. That eliminate the need to do the mutation explicitly (using slice)

Comment: what happens with one element?

Comment: @NinaScholz you get an oxford comma? ;)

Comment: @evolutionxbox though I like you comment you would actually have gotten a weird string "Content tagged and tag".

Comment: Yep. The actual result wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Updated accordingly. Thanks @ninascholtz

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var g = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];
var title = g.slice(0, g.length-1).join(',').concat(' and ').concat(g[g.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be my approach

```js
function arrayFormat(arr) {
    var output = arr.splice(0, arr.length - 1).join(", ");
    output += " and " + arr[0];
    return output;
}
console.log(arrayFormat(["a", "b", "c"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

From my view, This is an simple approach

```
var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];

console.log("Content tagged " + tags.slice(0, -1).join(', ')+' and '+tags.slice(-1));
```

Hope it helps you :)
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gybadxtc/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var arr = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']; 
var lastStr = arr.pop();
var str = "Content tagged " + arr.join(", ") + " and " + lastStr;
```